# Can I salvage an over-watered tomato plant?

Tags: containers, tomatoes, plant-care

I've never tried growing tomatoes before and I recently went out and bought a tomato plant for my balcony.  I initially re-potted the plant in too small a planter, so I re-re-potted it a week later.  Each time I watered thoroughly, perhaps too thoroughly, and also added a bit too much fertilizer, which I later attempted to wash away by (yes) more watering.  Now, 2 weeks later, all the leaves are wilted and the tomatoes that started growing have stopped getting bigger.  I tried draining the soil by lifting up the tomato plant and replacing wet soil that didn't yet have any roots with fresh, relatively dry soil.

Is there anything else I can do to stimulate this plant back to life?

Comment: They use the term helicopter parent... But this seems like the appropriate time to coin the term helicopter gardener... Leave that plant alone, do not try to replace its soil, water it normally, see if it lives...

Answer (score 4):

IF all else fails, and you still have sort of healthy looking tips on some of the branches, then you can take a cutting of a few of them and try to start over.  Tomatoes will root green tips in a glass of water or placed into moist soil with a perforated plastic bag over the rest of the cutting to keep the humidity high.  Make your cuttings at least 4 inches long and strip off the lower set or two of leaves.  Keep it in bright, but not direct light, until you see new growth, then give it a bit more light.